# Running Javascript every X seconds - what's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, function, rotation, alert

I am using this code to detect when the device is in landscape but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
 function OrientationAlert {
if(window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth){
    alert("Please rotate your device and view this in portrait orientation.");
   }

   setInterval(OrientationAlert, 5000);
}
```

Comment: one problem is your OrientationAlert function doesn't have () after it like `function OrientationAlert() {` Check out my answer to see your other problem...

Comment: I can't put any code outside of function due to software limitations. Is this possible without putting it after the function is closed?

Comment: There is a problem here somewhere you have to call `OrientationAlert` whether it's on `page load` `onAfterRendering` etc...

Comment: @brso05 I am loading this in the page load as it is.

Comment: you should have no problem putting code outside your `OrientationAlert` function then...

Comment: like I said before `OrientationAlert` has to be triggered (called) from somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function OrientationAlert(){
if(window.innerWidth < 500){
    setInterval(function(){
    if(window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth){
        alert("Please rotate your device and view this in portrait orientation.");
       }
    }, 5000);
    }
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body onload="OrientationAlert()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Try this out!!

Update:- added condition as per the requirements you mentioned under comments

```
 if(window.innerWidth < 500) {
//the setInterval() funcion is registered at the time of page or else it wont
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. I am running this when a page is first loaded and it should continue to run whilst the user is visiting that page.

Comment: oh ok.. edited my answer! `OrientaionAlert()` will be called on load of the page and will run whilst the user is visiting that page.

Comment: Ok that is definitely getting closer now :) Only issue is that it is for a responsive site and only wanted to call the function on two of the layouts. Can you think of any way I could call it on page load for a select number of layouts? perhaps using: if (screen.width >= XXX) {} but then again would that work as there if another if statement later on?

Comment: I have added a check for the screen width of the device, would this be ideal for you?

Comment: That's what I would have thought to do but it doesn't work when I do that

Comment: hmm..!! Strange!! umm.. what error do you get on console? which browser? device on which you are testing as of now is laptop right?

Comment: I am using a desktop and set it to work if the device is less than 500.

Comment: u mean, the condition you have written is `if(screen.width < 500){//setInterval(code)}`?? is the browser Chrome? can you check what your device width is?

Comment: if your device width is more than 500 (I think it would be), you wont get that alert. If you want to test it on desktop,  change the condition to `if(screen.width > 500){//setInterval(code)}`, you should get that alert message. If then also it doesn't work, well we have to debug more. However, if it works change the condition to `if(screen.width < 500){//setInterval(code)}` and push the code, if you are trying to target devices which have width less than 500px. It will work!

Comment: I am using safari. The device width is definitely less than 500. The window is as thin as it can be when scaled.

Comment: that's the trouble.. there is a difference between device width and window width. `screen.width` gives the width of the device not the browser window which is `window.innerWidth`.  Change your condition to `if(window.innerWidth < 500){//setInterval(code)}` and it should work.

Comment: Ah that is it. I think you have solved it :) Will let you know if I have any other issues. Thanks

Comment: Sure! you are welcome! you had me scratching my head for sometime. :D All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   if(window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth){
     alert("Please rotate your device and view this in portrait orientation.");
   } 
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could as well use the `orientationchange` event.
Here is an example:

```
function doOnOrientationChange() {
    switch(window.orientation)
    {
        case -90:
        case 90:
            alert('landscape');
            break;
        default:
            alert('portrait');
            break;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);

// Initial execution if needed
doOnOrientationChange();
```

The browser support is not too bad and since it will only come into play an mobile devices it might be an option for you. Here is what can i use says [Link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=deviceorientation).

Here you can find more information on the

[Screen Orientation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/).

You can as well declare it in a callback function like so:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
    switch(window.orientation)
    {
        case -90:
        case 90:
            alert('landscape');
            break;
        default:
            alert('portrait');
            break;
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could I put any code inside of the function somehow as due to the software I am using, I cannot put anything outside of the function

Comment: What exactly do you mean as due to the software? You could put anything in the switch case statement.

Comment: Basically, it doesn't let me type any code after the closing bracket of the function. It is a visual based builder and I am currently using a button which on click will run a javascript function.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer. With the callback function you basically do not need to put anything outside the function.

Comment: Can you join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81572/orientationchange

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = OrientationAlert {...}
setInterval(a,5000);
```